# Cannot locate driver for Derby database

Tags: java, driver, derby

I have a simple Web Application setup inside netbeans IDE. Having a spot of trouble when trying to connect the persistence layer.

The database itself is Apache Derby. I've set the DERBY.jar to the classpath, and I've added both DERBY.jar and DERBYCLIENT.jar to the lib folder of the application.

The code is appended below. The database path is set correctly, as are the username and password variables.

```
  private static final String     DB_URL      = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB";

public void dbConnection(){
    System.out.println("Attempting to establish a connection to a database");
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
    System.out.println("Driver Loaded");

    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);   
        System.out.println("Successfully Connected to DERBY DATABASE");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the DERBY DATABASE");
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont know whats happening here:  `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();` but you are ignoring the instance returned.

Comment: Hi Satellite. This is a code reuse on my part, from my MySQL database connections, which worked perfectly. Could you suggest what it is I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace

Comment: Hi Kode. Stack trace is as follows

Attempting to establish a connection to a database
Driver Loaded
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/myDB
Could not connect to the DERBY DATABASE

Comment: It sounds like it's not finding derbyclient.jar in your CLASSPATH. But you can get more information from the exception and find out for sure: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Hi Brian, I believe the derbyclient.jar is necessary for servers only. The database itself is running locally on my machine, but I will try your suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: just guessing, but what happens if you alter `DB_URL` to somthing similar like this: `jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true`, i.e. removing `//localhost:1527/`. ref: db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've actually solved this problem by using the client driver as opposed to the Embedded Driver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by using the client driver as opposed to the Embedded Driver inside of the persistence setup code.